# Filtering a stream of pojos using values from a map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this pojo (This is an example of the case, not the real one):

```
Book {
  String name;
  Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

and a list of them:

```
List<Book> library;

TheBook1, {["lang", "pt-br"],["type","romance"],["author","John"]}
TheBook2, {["lang", "en-US"],["type","fiction"],["author","Brian"],["translation","pt-br,es"}
```

Suppose that I have a Library collection and I have a map containing search criteria, like:

```
Map<String, String> criteria = new HashMap<>();
criteria.put(BOOK_TYPE, "romance");
criteria.put(BOOK_LANG, "pt-br");
```

How could I write a filter predicate for the library stream in order to search for all books that fulfil the provided criteria? The match must be a exact String match of the both key and value for now.

Something like this:

```
Set<Book> result = library.stream()
.filter(b-> b.getProperties() **????**)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: btw, if you don't care about the keys of the HashMap that contains the filters, why don't you make it a HashSet?

Comment: It seems you want to test if Map A contains all entries from Map B. Do you have any other requirements because I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @MaxG, I do care, because in the API it is a Map and I can't change it.

Comment: @zeroflagL, indeed is what I wanted. the problem is that I do not knew how to do this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply have:

```
List<Book> books = 
    library.stream()
           .filter(b -> b.properties.entrySet().containsAll(criteria.entrySet()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will filter books by only keeping those whose properties contain all of the given criteria. The check is done using [`containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-), which means that it will retain properties containing exactly the given criteria (matching by equality of entries, so equality of both keys and values).

Comment: good answer, I would just add that this will work because Map.Entry overrides equals/hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

`library` is a `List<Book>` i guess?

---

Just think about how you would write the predicate without using Java8 / Streams. And then just place your predicate within the `filter` method.

I.e.:

```
Book b = ...;
boolean matches = false;
if(b.properties != null) {
  for(Entry<String,String> e : b.properties) {
    if(e.getKey().equals("foo") && e.getValue().length > 3) {
      matches = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

(I know this filter could be written much more simple using, optimize it if needed)

Now create a method from this:

```
public static boolean myPredicate(Book b) {
  if(b.properties != null) {
    for(Entry<String,String> e : b.properties) {
      if(e.getKey().equals("foo") && e.getValue().length > 3) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And then place it within your stream:

```
Set<Book> result = library.stream()
  .filter(MyClass::myPredicate)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

You could also place it directly within the `filter` method:

```
Set<Book> result = library.stream()
  .filter(b -> {
    if(b.properties != null) {
      for(Entry<String,String> e : b.properties) {
        if(e.getKey().equals("foo") && e.getValue().length > 3) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

Btw: You shouldn't need the `toSet` collector. Just create a `List`. Should be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax:

```
Set<Book> filteredBooks = library
    .stream()
    .filter((a) -> {
                boolean answer;
                for(Entry<Integer, String> filter : filters.entrySet())
                    if (!isTrue(a, filter.getValue().getProperty())) return false;
                return true;
                   })
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

While `filters` is actually the `Map` of criteria that you have. "`get(1)`" is your first criteria etc. I used `isTrue` as a method that returns `boolean` for books that pass the criteria. As you can see, you can use multiple criteria. No problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks... but the problem I see with this solution is that I do not know and can't foresee the number of criteria that the user will input

Comment: @Cristiano you can run a loop on `filters.keySet().size()`

Comment: @Cristiano iv'e edited the code to match the unknown user input.

Answer (score 1):

As [**that**](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#section4) says, the body of the lambda expression can be either a single expression or a statement block. So you can write your predicate like this: (t) -> { //statement 1; // statement2; //return result;}.

```
Set<Book> result = library.stream()
            .filter( b -> {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : criteria.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if (!(b.getProperties().get(key) != null && b.getProperties().get(key).equals(entry.getValue()))) return false;
    }
    return true;
})
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Otherwise, you can replace your criteria with its predicate format:

```
Set<Book> result3 = library.stream()
            .filter( b -> b.getProperties().get("BOOK_TYPE").equals("romance") && b.getProperties().get("BOOK_LANG").equals("Pt-Br"))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or,

```
Predicate<Book> bookType = b -> b.getProperties() != null &&  b.getProperties().get("BOOK_TYPE") != null && b.getProperties().get("BOOK_TYPE").equals("romance");
Predicate<Book> bookLang = b -> b.getProperties() != null && b.getProperties().get("BOOK_LANG") != null && b.getProperties().get("BOOK_LANG").equals("Pt-Br");
Set<Book> result3 = library.stream()
            .filter(bookType)
            .filter(bookLang)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```